# .htaccess RewriteCond where URI does not contain domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have looked around on Google and StackOverflow for the answer to this question, but the fact that I don't know much about .htaccess doesn't help me decide what the correct answers for my situation are, so I am asking here.

My situation is that I have several sites that are using the same physical directory as their root on the server.

This is all working fine but I wanted to make sure that each site can't access each others images etc from the browser unless they are on the correct domain.

Currently I have a file structure like this:

```
/resources/{resource}/{full_domain_name}
```

So for example `www.domain.co.uk` would have a structure like this:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/resources/images/www.domain.co.uk/some_image.jpg
```

But if `www.domain_2.co.uk` exists using the same physical directory for the site root then they can look at other domain's resources from their own domain, like this:

```
http://www.domain_2.co.uk/resources/images/www.domain.co.uk/some_image.jpg
```

This isn't really a major problem since there is absolutely no sensitive information stored in these directories, but it's more of an annoyance and I would rather users were not able to do it (not that anyone actually has so far).

I tried putting a .htaccess file into the /resources directory but I'm stuck with the regular expressions etc.

I basically want to make sure that the URI contains the current domain name otherwise redirect to a 403 error page.

This is what I came up with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/resources/[^/]*/%{HTTP_HOST})(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error/403.php
```

The reason I put in the `[^/]` bit is because there are several folders, for example:

```
/resources/images/{full_domain_name}
/resources/scripts/{full_domain_name}
/resources/stylesheets/{full_domain_name}
```

Could anybody help me with these conditions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of your current rule? It looks like it would work, except that you don't need any `()` around `/resources/[^/]*/%{HTTP_HOST}.*`

Comment: @Michael Currently if I am on www.domain.co.uk and go to www.domain.co.uk/resources/stylesheets/www.domain.co.uk/style.css for example it always redirects me to the /error/403.php file. When I remove the .htaccess rule it finds the file as it should do normally.

Comment: You don't actually need the whole `%{REQUEST_URI}` represented in the regex. You can just match the http_host `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your reply. I just tried the RewriteCond that you gave me but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: I have a feeling that the `/resources...` should be `resources...`  in the regex. Since it is in the same folder I believe the preceding slash should be omitted. Also, this will "403" anything not in the resources folder & its subfolders. If this is not intended behaviour, you need two `RewriteCond`s: one to check that it is in the resources folder, and then another to check for the domain mismatch (which you have).

Comment: @Sour Lemon: typo at `%{REQUEUST_URI}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is terrific question and if I could I would have upvoted 10+ times. I am posting my answer even though you have an accepted answer here as I really had to dig through all my Apache resources to come up with the answer. Here is the rule you will need for this problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^:]+):/resources/[^/]+/\1/.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^resources/[^/]+/[^/]+/.+ - [F,NC,NE]
```

PS: Since we cannot use `%` variables on RHS as back-reference, I am using special regex back-reference variable `\1` in the `RewriteCond` here.

Comment: I don't usually do this but in this case I think I will change my accepted answer, since this provides a perfect solution to the problem. Thank you for posting your answer anubhava, it's much appreciated!

Comment: You're most welcome and thank you for posting such an interesting problem that made me learn new mod_rewrite tricks as well :).

Answer (score 3):

This condition is insufficient:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEUST_URI} !^(/resources/[^/]*/%{HTTP_HOST})(.*)$
```

Because if I request anything that doesn't start with `/resources/`, I'll get the 403.php error page. What you really want is something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !%1
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/[^/]+/%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

Where the first condition is checking that the request is for a resource, then the second checking the host. **HOWEVER**, neither of these will work because mod_rewrite's `RewriteCond` directive doesn't allow **%** variables or backreferences in the right hand side of the condition, only the left. Likewise, you cannot do this either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resources/[^/]+/([^/]+)/
RewriteRule !^/resources/[^/]+/%{HTTP_HOST}/ /error/403.php
```

Because the RewriteRule's expression cannot have variables in it, since it's a regex, and it literally expects a `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of replacing it with the Host given in the request. So to conclude, no, you can't do this with mod_rewrite's conditions this way.

Something that you can try if you have access to either server config or vhost config is to create a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) and pass in both the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}`. So if your map is called `check_host` then your rule may look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^resources/[^/]+/([^/]+)/ ${check_host:%{HTTP_HOST}_%{REQUEST_URI}}
```

And your script will just need to parse the input, split it from the first `_`, parse the request URI and make sure the host is the same as the HTTP_HOST. If it's the same, output the same request URI, otherwise output the error URI. If you don't have access to server or vhost config, I think you're out of luck. RewriteMap cannot be defined in the htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Jon Lin. I didn't know that you couldn't put the % variables or back references into the right side of RewriteCond. I have opted to try the RewriteMap but if for any reason I can't do that then I'm sure I will find another way outside of mod_rewrite :)